# how to set image dynamically to li tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

i have jquery slider. this slider has images and thumb nails of those images. i would like to replace images and thumbnails respectively which comes from jquery ajax call.
this is my slider code:

```
<ul id="thumbs" class="slides">
    <li id="firstthumb" data-thumb="images/s/img8.jpg">
        <img id="firstimage" src="images/s/img8.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li id="secondthumb" data-thumb="images/s/img10.jpg">
        <img id="secondimage" src="images/s/img10.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li id="thirdthumb" data-thumb="images/s/img9.jpg">
        <img id="thirdimage" src="images/s/img9.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li id="fourththumb" data-thumb="images/s/img11.jpg">
        <img id="fourthimage" src="images/s/img11.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li id="fifththumb" data-thumb="images/s/img3.jpg">
        <img id="fifthimage" src="images/s/img3.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have replaced images with following code:

```
$('#firstimage').attr('src', message[22]);
$('#secondimage').attr('src', message[23]);
$('#thirdimage').attr('src', message[24]);
$('#fourthimage').attr('src', message[25]);
$('#fifthimage').attr('src', message[26]);
```

here message[22]... are urls of images. its working perfectly. but i don't know how to replace thumb nails images. give me some idea. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#firstthumb').data('thumb', message[22]);
```

OR

```
$('#firstthumb').attr('data-thumb',message[22]);
```

Comment: thank you. I have already tried with second one also. but not working.

Comment: @RameshJn make sure you have the image in that path. message[22]

Comment: yes the path is correct. its working for images. problem with thumbnails.. If path is incorrect atleast it should display some empty

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
  $('#firstimage').attr('src', message[22]).data('thumb', message[22]);
```

Comment: Can you provide some fiddle demo?